# Any "fundamentals-oriented" example of NSScroller out there?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm looking for some kind of a basic, straightforward example of how to work with a pair of NSScrollers in an NSScrollView with a custom NSView.

There are sporadic examples out there, largely consisting of contrived examples using programatically created interfaces, or based on the assumption that the developer is working with a typical ImageView or TextView. Even the Sketch example is based on an NSView that uses the Page Setup in the Print dialog for the bounds, and everything is managed by Cocoa. So there's no real discussion or examples anywhere of how make it all work using a custom Model (though that may be part of the problem, because what does one base the Model on?). Even Apple's own documentation is dodgy here.

Essentially, I have a sub-classed NSView enbedded in an NSScrollView (per the Scoll View Guide), that a user can click in the view to create, edit and delete objects, much like an illustration program. The Model is those objects that are just data wrappers that simply record their position for drawRect: to use. The height and width are based on custom values that are being translated into pixels as needed.

My problem is that all of the examples I have found are based on either a text editor, an image viewer, or uses the standard document sizes in the Page Setup dialog. Because these are common document types, Cocoa basically manages for the developer, so the interaction code is more or less hidden (or I'm just not seeing it for what it is). My project doesn't fit any of those needs, and I have no need for printing. Thrusting my Model into the documentView property wouldn't work.

I'm just looking for a simple example on how to initialize the NSScrollers with a custom, object-oriented Model (the documentView), and handle scrolling and updating based on user action, such as when the user drags a smattering of objects off to the left or down or the window gets resized. I think I'm close to getting it all together, but I'm missing the jumping off point that ties the controls to document.

(Not that it matters in a Cocoa question, but when I did this in REALbasic, I would simply calculate and apply the MaxX, MaxY to a ScrollBar's Maximum value based on user actions, watch the position in the ScrollBar when the user clicks, and draw as needed. NSScrollers in the NSScrollView context aren't nearly as obvious to me, it seems.)

*I appreciate the time taken by everyone, but I'm updating with more information in the hopes of getting an answer I can use.  I'm sorry, but none of this is making sense, Apple's documents are obtuse, but perhaps I'm missing something painfully obvious here...*

I have an array of objects sitting in a subclassed NSDocument which are data holders that tell drawRect what and where to draw. This is *straight* from the Sketch example. The Sketch example uses the document sizes in the Page Setup dialog for the size, so there's nothing to show here. I'm cool with Cocoa handling the state of the scroll bars, but how do I link up the ScrollView to see the initial editor's state held in the NSDocument and updates to those objects and the editor? Do I calculate my own NSRect and pass that to the NSScrollView? Where and how? Am I doing this in my custom NSView which has been embedded in the NSScrollView or my NSDocument in init? The NSScrollView isn't created programmatically (there's no easy way of doing that), so it's all sitting in Interface Builder waiting to be hooked up. I'm missing the hook up bit.

Perhaps I'm wearing my "I don't get it" cap this week, but this can't be this difficult. Illustration apps, MIDI Editors, and countless other similar custom apps do this all the time.

**SOLVED (mostly):**

I think I have this sorted out now, though it's probably not the best implementation.

My document class now has a NSRect DocumentRect property that looks at all of its objects and gives back a new NSRect based on their location. I call it in my subclassed NSView's mouse events with

```
[self setFrame:[[self EditorDocument] DocumentRect]];
```

This updates the size of the View based on user interaction, and the window now handles the scrolling where it didn't before.  At this point I'm figuring out how to get the frame to expand while dragging, but at least I now have the fundamental concept I was missing.

The answer given pointed me in the direction I needed to go here (documentView requiring a view, which translated to looking at the NSView class), so Peter gets the credit. Thanks so much for help.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There's not really enough information to answer your question. You're unlikely to use NSScroller by itself; NSScrollView should provide all the API you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The document view isn't a model, it's a view. That's why it's called the document *view*.

The reason there are so few examples on working with NSScrollers directly is because you normally don't. You work with NSScrollView and let it handle the scrollers for you.

All you need to do is make a view big enough to show the entire model, then set that as the document view of the scroll view. From there, it should Just Work. You don't need to manage any of the scrolling-related numbers yourself; Cocoa handles them for you.

For details, see the [Scroll View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/).

Comment: That's...creepy. What if the starting view is larger than the window itself? I'll give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: “What if the starting view is larger than the window itself?” Same deal. The very reason why you would put a view into a scroll view is that the view is larger than the view that would otherwise be its superview.